# Obtener el texto que coincide con un número al inicio del texto

Tags: java, regex

Intento obtener un número al inicio de un string, ignorando lo que siguiera después. Ocupo siempre capturar los decimales de uno hasta tres y lo que sigue ignorarlo. Y en caso de que sólo esté un punto, pues que se descarte.

Tengo esta expresión que me funciona bien en un editor de expresiones,  pero no sé si la estoy aplicando bien en Java.

Trato de obtener alguno de los grupos que coincidan con el patrón pero sólo obtengo toda la cadena. Los grupos me aparecen vacíos. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
private String filtraNumeros(String texto){

    String exprecion= "^([0-9]{1,12}\\.{1}[0-9]{1,3})|^([0-9]{1,12}).*$";


    int contador = 0;
    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(exprecion);
    Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(texto);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(contador));
        System.out.println("----"+contador);
        contador++;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Hay un par de cosas raras en la expresión... ¿con qué valor quieres hacer el match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problemas en tu regex

Hay 2 grupos en tu expresión:

```
"^([0-9]{1,12}\\.{1}[0-9]{1,3})|^([0-9]{1,12}).*$";
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         grupo 1               o     grupo 2
```

*Obtener el texto que coincidió*

El texto con el que coincidió **todo** el regex es devuelto por `.group(0)` (lo que es lo mismo que `.group()`).

Siempre se devolverán las capturas de los 2 [grupos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), por lo que no es necesario recorrerlas con un bucle. El texto capturado por el primer grupo siempre se obtiene con `.group(1)`, y el texto capturado por el grupo 2 siempre se obtiene con `.group(2)`. En tu expresión, sólo uno de estos grupos puede coincidir (es uno o el otro), por lo que uno devolverá el número y el que no se utilice para la coincidencia devolverá `null`.

*Una o múltiples coincidencias sobre el mismo texto*

El bucle en `while (matcher.find())` te sirve en caso de que haya más de una coincidencia en el string. Sin embargo, con la expresión que estás usando, como `^` coincide con el inicio del string y `$` coincide con el fin, sólo se podrá obtener 1 única coincidencia. Es decir que el `while` en este caso es redundante y podría reemplazarse por un `if`.

En definitiva, para una expresión que sólo puede coincidir una única vez con el texto, donde se captura con un grupo o el otro, el código se sería:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Optional;
```

```java
String regex = "^(exprA)|^(exprB)exprC$";

Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String grupoCapturado = Optional.ofNullable( //obtener el que no sea nulo
                                                   matcher.group(1) 
                                               ).orElse( 
                                                   matcher.group(2) 
                                               );
    System.out.println("Grupo capturado: " + grupoCapturado);
}
```

---

#### Obtener el número al inicio del string

La expresión que estás utilizando, podríamos reescribirla como:

```
"^\\d{1,12}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"
```

Esto es un número, opcionalmente con 1 a 3 decimales.

Simplemente obteniendo el valor de `matcher.group()` se obtiene el número, y el grupo 1 es opcional. Para obtener lo decimales capturados por el grupo 1 usaríamos `matcher.group(1)`.

**Código**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
private void filtraNumeros(String texto){

    String regex    = "^\\d{1,12}(\\.\\d{1,3})?";

    Pattern patron  = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(texto);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        //Imprimir todo el texto con el que se coincidió
        System.out.println( "Número: " + matcher.group());
        //Imprimir sólo el punto y los decimales (si tiene)
        if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
            System.out.println( "Decimales: " + matcher.group(1) );
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println( "No empieza con un número" );
    }
}
```

```java
// Prueba
String prueba ="123.45678 etc.";
filtraNumeros(prueba);
```

**Resultado**

```
Número: 123.456
Decimales: .456
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Iy43bU

> Si no es necesario capturar los decimales, también se puede utilizar
>   un [grupo sin captura](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).
>
> `(?:expresión)` es lo mismo que `(expresión)` pero no ocupa memoria
>   innecesaria en capturar el texto. Sería:
>
> ```
> "^\\d{1,12}(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?"
> ```

---

#### ¿Cómo obtener todos los números en un string?

Originalmente estabas usando `while (matcher.find())` con la intención de obtener todas las coincidencias en el texto. Para ello, no utilizaremos `^` ni `$`. En cambio, vamos a garantizar que no esté precedido por un dígito ni un punto, y que termine en un [límite de palabra completa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html). Eso nos permitirá coincidir con los diferentes números, en cualquier lugar dentro del texto.

**Expresión regular**

```
(?<![\d.])\d{1,12}(?:\.\d{1,3})?+\b
```

- `(?<![\d.])` - Inspección hacia atrás negativa.
  La posición actual no está precedida por:

  - `[\d.]` - [clase de caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc) - un [dígito](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) o un punto.
- `\d{1,12}` - entre 1 y 12 [dígitos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?+` [grupo sin captura](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), es [opcional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) con `?` y [posesivo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#poss) con `+`.
  Coincide con:

  - `\.` - un punto (literal).
  - `\d{1,3}` - entre 1 y 3 [dígitos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).
- `\b` - [límite de palabra completa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) (no está seguido por un alfanumérico ni `_`).

**Código**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
private void filtraNumeros(String texto){

    String regex    = "(?<![\\d.])\\d{1,12}(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?+\\b";

    Pattern patron  = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(texto);
    int contador = 0;

    //bucle para cada coincidencia.
    while (matcher.find()) {
        //Imprimir todo el texto con el que se coincidió
        System.out.println( ++contador + "° número: " + matcher.group() );
    }
}
```

```java
// Prueba
String prueba ="abc 123 def 12.345 -- demasiados decimales: 1.1234 987654321.321 0";
filtraNumeros(prueba);
```

**Resultado**

```
1° número: 123
2° número: 12.345
3° número: 987654321.321
4° número: 0
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/jieOuc

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Al final tuve que corregir la expresión y utilice la versión simplificada que propusiste quedando de esta manera `"^\\d{1,12}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"`. Elimine `$` del final por que obligaba a una coincidencia con el patrón y yo quería que solo ignorara lo que siguiera despues del patrón. Todo funciona muy bien. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Funciona mejor tu propuesta primera para lo que necesito. Ocupo siempre capturar los decimales de uno hasta tres y lo que sigue ignorarlo. y en caso de que solo este un punto pues que se descarte. De verdad, muchas gracias por tus comentarios son sumamente enriquecedores.

Answer (score 2):

[Del javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

> public boolean find()
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. 
>   This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods

Tu patrón contiene tanto el inicio `^` como el final de la cadena `$`. Por eso, *solo hará find una vez*.

Como solo puedes hacer find una vez, el único grupo que intentas mostrar es el grupo 0, que es la expresión que hace match en su conjunto (es decir, toda la cadena que le pasas).

Lo que tienes que hacer es hacer el bucle sobre el número de grupos encontrados, que puedes obtener con [`groupCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount())

Así pues, quedaría:

```
if (matcher.matches()) {  // queda más claro que sólo habrá un match<sup>1</sup>
    for (int contador = 0; contador < matcher.groupCount(); contador++) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(contador));
       System.out.println("----"+contador);
    }
}
```

Obviamente, solo aparecerán los grupos 0 y 1 (no hay más paréntesis).

Sobre la expresión regular, dos cosas:

- `{1}` sobra. Si pones `\\.`, ya indicas que solo quieres uno.
- Igual queda mejor agrupando la parte común. Algo como:

  ```
  "^([0-9]{1,12}(?:\\.{1}[0-9]{1,3})?).*$";
  ```

que se lee como "de 1 a 12 dígitos, que puede ir seguido de 0 o 1 ocurrencias de `.` seguido por de 1 a 3 dígitos". El `?:` indica que el contenido de ese grupo no debe ser capturado - no aparecerá en `groups` ni en `groupCount`-.

Además, queda más legible con clases (`\\d` en vez de `[0-9]`)

---

<sup>1</sup>`while (matcher.find()) {` funcionaría igualmente. Pero si le estás pasando una expresión regular donde solo puede haber un `find()`, el `if`(matcher.matches()) {` se lee mejor.

Comment: Ojo que `.group(2)` sí existe cuando hay 2 grupos en el regex.

Comment: @Mariano mmmm... no sé porqué pensaba que el número de los grupos se asignaba según se capturaban, no según aparecían en la expresión. Voy a repasar la respuesta, gracias.